# 403 Java error no permission

Tags: java, http-status-code-403

Everytime I try to load a .png file through a Java project it gives me a 403 error. The odd thing is, it worked for any other host I was using before until I got the one I'm currently using. I've been doing some research and it seems like it's caused by the headers, since it's being checked by my host so it assumes the client is a bot so it will get a 403 error.

```
private static Sprite BACKGROUND;
    static {
        try {
            BACKGROUND = new Sprite(new URL("http://www.CENSORED/client/bg.png"));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The image is used here:

```
BACKGROUND.drawSprite((frameWidth / 2) - (BACKGROUND.myWidth / 2), (frameHeight / 2) - (BACKGROUND.myHeight / 2));
```

Error:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://www.CENSORED.com/client/bg.png
```

I'm not sure where I can add the headers or anything that would help me bypass this error.

Comment: Could be multiple reasons behind this... Could be that you're not sending any good "User-Agent" headers. Could be their policy to only serve whitelisted request origins. etc.

Comment: Could you access to the image from the server without using Java?

For example if you are in linux using wget?

May be there are a proxy between you and the network?

Comment: the 403 means：`The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated. If the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make public why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the reason for the refusal in the entity. If the server does not wish to make this information available to the client, the status code 404 (Not Found) can be used instead.`  you can check the `http://www.CENSORED.com/client/bg.png` read permission

Answer (score 0):

Could you be facing a CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) issue?

A resource makes a cross-origin HTTP request when it requests a resource from a different domain than the one which the first resource itself serves. For example, an HTML page served from domain-a.com makes an img src request for domain-b.com/image.jpg. Many pages on the web today load resources like CSS stylesheets, images and scripts from separate domains.

For security reasons, browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests initiated from within scripts.  For example, XMLHttpRequest follows the same-origin policy. So, a web application using XMLHttpRequest could only make HTTP requests to its own domain. To improve web applications, developers asked browser vendors to allow XMLHttpRequest to make cross-domain requests.

More information

```
[1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS
[2]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing
[3]: http://www.enable-cors.org
```